# Error on Subscription not hitting on HttpClient Call

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular6

When my API returns an error (for ex: Status Code 400) my error on subscription is not being hit. I have wrapped my httpclient calls in a service called RestDataService that all services can use to do REST based calls.

Than I have another service called SampleService which injects the RestDataService and has a method called uploadFile which calls my api endpoint.

So, once I inject the Service into my CallingClass and call the uploadMap from the Service than the error handle never fires. I'm not exactly sure why.

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RestDataService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    }

    public post(URL: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.post<any>(URL, data, { withCredentials: environment.withCredentials  })
            .pipe(catchError(err => this.handleError('post:' + URL, err)));
    }

    private handleError(url: string, err: any) {
        console.error('RestDataService server error:', err);
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            let errMsg: string;
            const errDetail = JSON.stringify(err.error);
            errMsg = `${err.status} - ${err.statusText || ''} URL: ${url} Message: ${err.message} Details: ${errDetail}`;
            return throwError(new Error(errMsg));
        }
        return throwError(err || 'RestDataService server error');
    }
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SampleService {

    constructor(restDataService: RestDataService) {
        const BASE_URL = environment.Endpoint;
        super(restDataService, BASE_URL);
    }

    public upLoadMap(data: any): Observable<any> {
        const URL = this.BASE_URL + 'par/;
        return this.restDataService.post(URL, data);
    }
}

export class CallingClass {
    constructor(private service: Service, private dialogRef: MatDialogRef) {}

    public uploadMap(xml: any) {
        const data = {
            xmlFile: window.btoa(xml)
        };
        this.service.upLoadMap(data).subscribe(parseData => {
                this.dialogRef.close({data: parseData});
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log(err);
                this.dialogRef.close();
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a play with catchError and the subscription throws the exception "TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."

```js
const { throwError } = rxjs;
const { catchError } = rxjs.operators;

throwError('error').pipe(
  catchError(err => { console.log(`From catchError: ${err}`); })
).subscribe(val => { console.log(val); }, err => { console.log(`From sub: ${err}`); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't have a catch error your subscription gets an observable exception instead of undefined and the error handler works fine.

```js
const { throwError } = rxjs;
const { catchError } = rxjs.operators;

throwError('error').pipe(
  //catchError(err => { console.log(`From catchError: ${err}`); })
).subscribe(val => { console.log(val); }, err => { console.log(`From sub: ${err}`); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Maybe you can try a tap to get into the error, doesn't destroy the observable on error

```js
const { throwError } = rxjs;
const { tap } = rxjs.operators;

throwError('error').pipe(
  tap(undefined, err => { console.log(`From tap: ${err}`); })
).subscribe(val => { console.log(val); }, err => { console.log(`From sub: ${err}`); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. I tried to add the .pipe(tap(undefined, err => { console.log(`From tap: ${err}`); })) to my CallingClass  but it never hit when the http response was 400.